How to make an expo module that uses react native vision camera?
My goal is to make an expo module to have my own functions to apply to frames coming from react native vision camera, similarly to existing plugins. However all the current plugins are not made using expo modules and there is no documentation about it.
As soon as I declare a function taking a frame from react native vision camera in my module, the app crashes without telling me why. I suppose it is because I haven't registered the frame processor plugin correctly but I cannot get it to work.
My current code is the following:
    class MlkitTextRecognitionModule : Module() {
  // Each module class must implement the definition function. The definition consists of components
  // that describes the module's functionality and behavior.
  // See https://docs.expo.dev/modules/module-api for more details about available components.
  companion object {
    init {
      FrameProcessorPluginRegistry.addFrameProcessorPlugin("recognizeTextFromFrame") { proxy, options ->
        MlkitTextRecognitionFrameProcessor(proxy, options)
      }
    }
  }

  override fun definition() = ModuleDefinition {

    Name("MlkitTextRecognition")

    // Sets constant properties on the module. Can take a dictionary or a closure that returns a dictionary.
    Constants(
      "PI" to Math.PI
    )
    // Defines event names that the module can send to JavaScript.
    Events("onChange")

    Function("recognizeTextFromUri") { uri: String ->
      val file = File(uri)
      if (!file.exists()) {
        throw Exception("File not found at: $uri")
      }

      // Load the image from the URI
      val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
      val inputImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0)

      // Perform text recognition
      val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(JapaneseTextRecognizerOptions.Builder().build())
      val visionText = try {
        Tasks.await(recognizer.process(inputImage))
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw Exception("Text recognition failed: ${e.message}")
      }

      visionText.text
    }

// CRASHES IF I UNCOMMENT IT
//    Function("recognizeTextFromFrame") { frame: Frame ->

//    }

My MlkitTextRecognitionFrameProcessor class is simply :
class MlkitTextRecognitionFrameProcessor(proxy: VisionCameraProxy, options: Map<String, Any>?): FrameProcessorPlugin() {
    override fun callback(frame: Frame, arguments: Map<String, Any>?): Any? {
        return "hello"
    }
}

